# This doesnt appear to work - count text length

Tags: jquery

This jQuery doesnt appear to be working as I would expect it to:

```
$('#topic li a').filter(function () {
  if ($(this).text() > 410) {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('wrap');
  }
});
```

The jQuery should work out if the text within an `<a href=>....</a>` is over 410 chars, if it is it should add the class .wrap to the parent li.

Anyone have any ideas what im doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: What do you think `$(this).text()` returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#topic li a').filter(function () {
  if ($(this).text().length > 410) {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('wrap');
  }
});
```

When you do `$(this).text() > 410` it tries to convert the text to an integer to compare, it most likely is converting the long string to a number like 0.  Use `.length` to get the length of the string returned

Answer (score 10):

jQuery's `text()` function returns a normal string.
By writing `$(this).text() > 410`, you are checking whether the string *itself* is more than 410, by trying to parse the string as a number.

You need to check the *length* of the string, like this:

```
if ($(this).text().length > 410)
```

Answer (score 2):

[SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)' answer is good already but I'm confused with your code.

Maybe you want to write it this way,

```
$('#topic li a').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().length > 410;
}).parent('li').addClass('wrap');
```

or use `.each()`,

```
$('#topic li a').each(function(){
  if ($(this).text().length > 410) {
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('wrap');
  }
});
```